# application version update sniplets

Tags: java, migration, liquibase

There are many frameworks to automatically update database schema's, Liquibase being a good example. This works fine for simple database changes like adding fields or changing the datatype, but when the change involves changing actual data, updating maybe involve executing business logic written in Java. Liquibase does support a java changeset, but usually (in order to have the database match the entities) Liquibase runs before the EJB services are up.

What I'm looking for is a framework that manages and executes Java sniplets, similar to Liquibase, but run separate.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a second run of Liquibase that is executed after the EJB services start. In the second changelog, use CustomTaskChange implementations that do whatever buisiness logic you want.

The built-in Liquibase execution methods are built to run early in the process, but you can easily use the liquibase.Liquibase API to embed the new call to Liquibase in whatever code works best for you.